# Decide which of the following functions are integrable on $[0,2]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have trouble detecting the integral of two quite similar functions

The first one is $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x  & ( 0\le x < 1) \\ x-2  &  ( 1\le x \le 2 )\end{cases}$$

The second one is $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x  & ( 0\le x \le 1) \\ x-2  &  ( 1\lt x \le 2 )\end{cases}$$

Are they both integrable?

If so, are their integrals the same?

Answer (score 1):

> Both of the functions are integrable and both have the same integral.

A very crude reasoning would be to say that integrals are *infinite* sums, so the value of the function at a particular point in general matters least.

Comment: You're welcome.